# Is TypeScript able to 'const' assertions to number calculation?

Tags: typescript

Please see this minimum example, this is my real usage:

```js
const SECONDS_A_MINUTE = 60; // the type is 60 here
const SECONDS_A_HOUR = SECONDS_A_MINUTE * 60; // the type is number here
```

[image]
[image]

I know `as const` is not available to a number calculation right now, and I know TypeScript will widen anything to `literal type` as well, but is it possible to annotate TypeScript to figure that number out for me?

Is there any utility type could achieve this?

Comment: Just write `SECONDS_A_HOUR  = 360` and there you go :D. It is not possible for TS to calculate any operation, TS is not doing runtime computation.

Comment: @MaciejSikora your hour is only six minutes long.

Comment: Good point :) hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the [`@rimbu/typical`](https://github.com/rimbu-org/rimbu/tree/main/packages/typical) library to allow type-level calculations. It uses some trickery but works reasonably well.

In your case, you would just have to write a multiplication function that takes the correct types like so:

```
import { Num } from '@rimbu/typical'

function mult<N1 extends number, N2 extends number>(n1: N1, n2: N2): Num.Mult<N1, N2> {
  return n1 * n2 as any;
}

const SECONDS_A_MINUTE = 60;
const SECONDS_A_HOUR = mult(SECONDS_A_MINUTE, 60);
// the type of SECONDS_A_HOUR is now inferred to be 3600
```

I'm not sure it's worth the trouble in this case, but it's nice that it's at least possible.

You can find more examples of how to use the package in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rimbu-sandbox-d4tbk?previewwindow=console&view=split&editorsize=65&moduleview=1&module=/src/typical/num.ts&file=/src/typical/num.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Right now I don't think this is possible.  The missing feature is type-level arithmetic, which is currently not a part of the language.  If you want to see this happen, you might want to go to the relevant GitHub issues [microsoft/TypeScript#15645](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15645) and [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382)
 and give them a  or possibly describe your use case if you think it's particularly compelling.

---

A near miss is trying to use [numeric enums](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members), which allow you to perform such basic arithmetic:

```
const enum CALCS { 
  SECONDS_A_MINUTE = 60, 
  SECONDS_A_HOUR = SECONDS_A_MINUTE * 60 
} 
const secondsPerHour = CALCS.SECONDS_A_HOUR;
```

And if you hover over `SECONDS_A_HOUR` in your IDE, the quickinfo IntelliSense will say `(enum member) CALCS.SECONDS_A_HOUR = 3600`, and in fact the above code will even emit the following JavaScript:

```
const secondsPerHour = 3600 /* SECONDS_A_HOUR */;
```

This is because `CALCS` is a [`const enum`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums).  If you make it a regular `enum` you'll still see the literal `3600` in the emitted JavaScript though.  The point is that the compiler is doing the math, not the runtime.

---

Unfortunately the language really doesn't give you a handle on that number `3600`. If you try to compute the type in the language, you get an error:

```
type SecondsPerHour = CALCS.SECONDS_A_HOUR; // error!
// -----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Enum type 'CALCS' has members with initializers that are not literals.
// type is just CALCS.
```

You'd need another missing feature, [microsoft/TypeScript#35875](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35875) for that error to go away.  For now the type of the value `CALCS.SECONDS_A_HOUR` is just `CALCS`, the enum type.

So this seems like a dead end, too.

---

Oh well, wish I had better news.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYQIIBk0GUYDeAUDDLgKJoDyAcgCK4D6GjAsgJI0CqAKuTAF4YANgAMAGhJlKtBs0YAJKlwBKg6dXpMWHbnxgAqEaKIBfIqEiwIcSwBMIABTgAnBSEQv1mHLgB0FJpyLEqqANxERFAAngAOcGS24A7Obh5eQj54ATJa8qEqYTAA9MXwLi4gLgCERKUwALRNzS2tTQB8MAB+Pb19-f11ZeRIqDHxMADkWbiTMAAWAIYQMMhwyABGrisA7gCWUPMwe2AHe4sANnsAXtswh4uwiy4JYCCwV1CulxB+Q-dxBJ7FYAK0Q0HQ2GyJCAA)