# TypeScript: Want to build a literal type with expression(s)

Tags: typescript

In the following code:

```js
const byLiteral = 3;
const byExpression = 1 + 2;
```

`byLiteral`'s type is 3, while `byExpression`'s type is `number`.

I want `byExpression`'s type to be 3.

Maybe it's somewhat self-contradicting since `1 + 2` is an expression (albeit a 'constant' expression) and not a literal, it can be useful like in the following situation for example.

```js
const BitsByLiteral = {
    BIT0: 1,
    BIT1: 2,
    BIT2: 4
} as const;

const BitsByExpression = {
    BIT0: 1 << 0,
    BIT1: 1 << 1,
    BIT2: 1 << 2
} as const;
```

`BitsByLiteral`'s type is

```js
const BitsByLiteral: {
    readonly BIT0: 1;
    readonly BIT1: 2;
    readonly BIT2: 4;
}
```

While `BitsByExpression`'s type is

```js
const BitsByExpression: {
    readonly BIT0: number;
    readonly BIT1: number;
    readonly BIT2: number;
}
```

Is there any way to this?

Comment: No, sorry... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069026/is-typescript-able-to-const-assertions-to-number-calculation) and its answer.  It is currently not possible.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. I think that the feature for my question is a simpler one than the feature for that question (since in my question there is no reference to the other const). But anyway it seems that it is not possible for now... (Typescript issue #26382 which is referenced in that question's answer is relevant to my question.)